# Анализ логов IIS с использованием pandas

Tags: python, pandas, логирование, iis

Задача сама по себе не сложная и решается силами чистого питона плюс-минус понятно, но пытаюсь прикрутить к ее решению pandas. Раньше для подобных задач все конвертил в эксель, но в данном случае (около 6 млн строк) эксель дает дуба :)
Есть логи IIS и я хочу получить из них информацию о количестве запросов к серверу, например в интервалы по 10 минут (т.е. это разбиение на временные интервалы)

из логов получил датафрейм (взял маленький кусок для примера):

```
 df = get_dataframe(get_log_list())
 
date        time            cs-username  timestamp  0
2022-05-17  01:36:55                   - 2022-05-17 01:36:55 1    
2022-05-17  01:36:59        test1        2022-05-17 01:36:59 2    
2022-05-17  01:37:09                   - 2022-05-17 01:37:09 3    
2022-05-17  01:37:10        test1        2022-05-17 01:37:10 4    
2022-05-17  04:51:55                   - 2022-05-17 04:51:55 ...
```

1. Никак не могу разобраться, как получить количество запросов к серверу поинтервально (с шагом в 10 минут, например):
   то есть получить результат, для приведенного примера, вида:

```
    2022-05-17 01:20:00 - 0  
    2022-05-17 01:30:00 - 25  
    2022-05-17 01:40:00 - 100  
    2022-05-17 01:50:00 - 300  
    etc
```

2. Как в целом применять условие "учитывать только запросы где "cs-username равно какому-то определенному значению или пустому". например учитывать при подсчете только запросы без авторизации, т.е. с пустым юзернеймом или наоборот?

Comment: Приведите пример данных (кусок вашего датафрейма в виде csv для воспроизведения).

Comment: 2022-05-17  01:36:55 - 2022-05-17 01:36:55
2022-05-17  01:36:59 test1 2022-05-17 01:36:59    
2022-05-17  01:37:09 - 2022-05-17 01:37:09    
2022-05-17  01:37:10 test1 2022-05-17 01:37:10    
2022-05-17  04:51:55 - 2022-05-17 04:51:55

Comment: ну и что вы привели? как с этим работать? ссылку на файл на файлообменнике приложите , чоли...

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gwzw1vglrgt6kyv/1.xls?dl=0

ПРошу простить, не понял сразу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте как-то так:

```
# устанавливаем timestamp как индекс и преобразуем в тип datetime
df = pd.read_excel('1.xls',index_col='timestamp',parse_dates=True)

df = df.resample('10min').size()
>>> df.head()
'''
timestamp
2022-05-18 05:00:00     4
2022-05-18 05:10:00     0
2022-05-18 05:20:00    28
2022-05-18 05:30:00    56
2022-05-18 05:40:00    16
Freq: 10T, dtype: int64
```

а на счет *"учитывать только запросы где "cs-username равно какому-то определенному значению или пустому"*, вы можете использовать фильтрацию строк, например: `df[df['cs-username']=='test1']`